# difference between linear-by-linear association and binarylogistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

my question is in continuation of the question asked previously here namely "What does “linear-by-linear association” in SPSS mean?". And it was wonderfully answered with an example as follows-
"Suppose we investigate whether 78 employees' promotion (yes/no) is related to their performance ranking in the previous year (1-4, 1=low), as follows: 
Ranking 1: Not promoted 17, Promoted 2, Total 19.
Ranking 2: Not promoted 16, Promoted 4, Total 20.
Ranking 3: Not promoted 14, Promoted 6, Total 20.
Ranking 4: Not promoted 10, Promoted 9, Total 19.
SPSS shows a significant linear-by-linear association (p=.008) showing that there is a significant association between the ranking and being promoted."
However, when i did not get same p value with binary logistric regression.
Please explain. Thanks